# Deleting EFI partition after removing dual-boot CentOS

Tags: linux, partitioning, efi, diskpart, boot-partition

I installed CentOS 8 yesterday alongside my Windows 10 installation, and I assigned the partitions manually, creating the following: `/` , `/home`, `/swap`, `/boot/efi`.

Unfortunately, I didn't assign enough space to my home directory, and I also wanted to try installing another distro just for practice, so I deleted the Linux partitions using the Disk Management tool in Windows.

However, I can't seem to delete the `/boot/efi` partition (partition 4), which now stops me from reallocating the space to my Windows partition.
[image: Screenshot]

Is it safe if I delete the partition using `diskpart`, and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: _(An FYI due to a factually inaccurate answer, your Windows EFI partition is partition 1 on disk 0.)_ You need to use `diskpart` > `sel dis 0` > `sel par 4` > `del par override` > `exit`. Also, I'm not sure why you created a 1GB EFI partition... it only needs to be 103MB - 513MB [RAW; formatted size of 100MB - 500MB], with its size dictated by the OS being used, as the EFI boot files are only ~10MB in total.

Comment: Okay, thank you! That seemed to work for me. I followed a tutorial when making the partitions, and I think it said to use 1GB for the EFI partition? But that's good to know, next time I'll use 500MB if that is the maximum needed.

Comment: Don't use 500MB... use what CentOS recommends on _their_ install Wiki _(if some wiki was saying to use 1GB, whoever wrote the wiki clearly doesn't understand what the EFI partition is)_.  Using more than what an OS recommends is simply wasting space as the EFI files, regardless of OS, are only ~10MB in total.

Answer (score 0):

The EFI partition is shared between Windows and Linux, both are putting their bootloaders there.

It is also required for Windows to boot.

Comment: This answer is factually inaccurate... Windows EFI partition is partition 1 on Disk 0

Comment: You cannot have two active ESP - efi system partitions per drive. Partition tools only allow you to create one with boot or esp flags. You can move boot flag to a second FAT32 partition to use as a second ESP. Since actual definition of ESP is a GUID which UEFI needs, it may work, or you may have to change boot flag as removing boot flag may convert back to GUID for data partition. Grub may boot the Windows as it just is looking for files, not GUIDs. Normal install is one ESP per drive and all systems share that ESP with different folders.

Comment: @oldfred I'm unsure if you're referring to my comment... If so, I'm not aware of any Linux distro that will move Windows 10's EFI boot files to a new ESP, as Windows 10's ESP's GUID is saved in the BCD Store, which would result in Windows not booting after installing Linux and having to run `bootrec /rebuildbcd` from WinRE.  Do all distros use the same ESP GUID _(Windows requires `c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b`)_?

Comment: I was not assuming that Windows EFI boot files would or could be moved without some issue. I have seen users use two ESP, to have unique boots on one drive. Even two Windows, so both could be directly booted from grub. But that is unusual. One vendor even has another FAT32 partition with vendor UEFI bootable utilities and I do not think it ever shows boot flag. UEFI requires that GUID. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table is list of GUIDs.